# Выполнение кода с заданным интервалом

Tags: время, php

Подскажите, как выполнить код в скрипте заданное количество раз через определённый промежуток времени. К примеру, выполнить `$this->method();` 3 раза через 60 секунд?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JavaScript: setInterval+ajax`.

Comment: А всё-таки с помощью php?

Comment: В php интервалы вы никак не зададите. А вот если на AJAX делать запрос к php  через 3 секунды, получиться (наверно), то, что вам нужно

Comment: Я нашёл: В php есть sleep();

Comment: Тогда у вас скрипт будет загружаться 3 минуты:)

Answer (score 3):

```
for($i=0; $i<=2; $i++) {
   $this->method();
   sleep(600);
}
```

Comment: `sleep(60)` вероятно? Как правильно заметил @atnartur - скрипт будет загружаться 3 минуты. Всё-таки буду смотреть в сторону JS setInterval.

Answer (score 0):

[CRON](http://www.google.ru/search?client=opera&rls=ru&q=cron&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest)

Comment: Рассматривал такой вариант. Только как я понял с его помощью можно выполнять скрипты по расписанию, мне же надо выполнить метод из скрипта несколько раз на сервере хостера. Доступа к шелу у меня нет.